# Differential Equations - Did I solve it properly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I attempted answering the question but I am not too sure if I am correct.

A mass is moving in the horizontal and vertical directions. Its horizontal displacement
*x* is increasing with time *t* at a rate proportional to *x*, with constant of proportionality
*k*. Its rate of change of vertical displacement, with respect to time *t*, is
a function *f(x, t)* in *x* and *t*.

Express the information as a pair of ordinary differential equations.

My attempt:

For Horizontal Displacement

${\delta x\over \delta t}$$\propto$$x$

${\delta x\over \delta t}$ = $kx$

For Vertical Displacement  $\delta y \over\delta t$ = $f(x, t)$ : I assumed

${\delta x\over \delta t}$=$kx$ = *f'(x, t)*

Therefore,

$\int$${1\over x}$$\delta x$ = $\int$$k$$\delta$t

$lnx=kt+c$

$e^{lnx}=e^{kt+c}$

$x=e^{c}e^{kt}$

Making $A=e^c$

Giving  $f'(x, t) = x-Ae^{kt}$

Hopefully my working makes some sense.

Also the second part of the question states that given $y=sin(t)\sqrt(lnx)$ find $f(x, t)$. So I am not sure if what I calculated is correct as I thought I had already found $f(x, t)$

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first differential equation is right, except that I would write $\frac{dx}{dt}=kx$.

The second should be $\frac{dy}{dt}=f(x,t)$.

The first equation can be solved explicitly for $x$. You did that basically correctly, we have $x=Ae^{kt}$ for some constant $A$. But you were not asked to do that. The solving for $f'(x,t)$ was not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so for $y$ direction I workout $\delta^2 x \over \delta t^2$

Comment: For the added part of the question, you differentiate the given $y$ with respect to $t$. When you differentiate, using the product rule and the chain rule, part of the expression will involve $\frac{dx}{dt}$, which you know is $kx$, so you can get an explicit expression for $\frac{dy}{dt}$ in terms of $x$ and $t$.

Comment: So would I be correct in saying that using $x=Ae^{kt}$ I would get $\delta y \over \delta t $ = $sin(t) \sqrt {x t ln|A|}$

Comment: In the original question, as I pointed out, you were not asked to find $x$. You are not asked to find $x$ in the added part either, since you are asked to find $f(x,t)$. Just differentiate. After you have done it I can if you wish check whether you are right. It is a pure differentiation problem.

Comment: Okay thanks that helps a lot, so it follows that $\delta y \over \delta t $ = $\delta y \over \delta x$ X $\delta x \over \delta t $ therefore, $\delta y \over \delta t $ = $kxsin(t) \over 2x\sqrt(ln|x|)$ ?

Comment: We have $\frac{dy}{dt}=(\sin t)w+(\cos t)\sqrt{\ln x}$ where $w=\frac{d}{dt}(\sqrt{\ln x})$. Now you need only calculate $w$, using the chain rule. It looks as if you know how to do that, so you are getting close to right, except that you forgot the term $(\cos t)\sqrt{\ln x}$.

Comment: $w$= $1 \over 2x\sqrt(ln|x|)$ therefore, $\delta y \over \delta x$ = $sin(t)w + cos(t)\sqrt(lnx)$ where, $w$= $1 \over 2x\sqrt(ln|x|)$ ? Why cant we differentiate $\delta y \over \delta x$ to give $\delta y \over \delta t$ since we know $\delta x \over \delta t$

Comment: Not quite, $w$ is $\frac{dx}{dt}$ times the derivative of $\sqrt{\ln x}$ with respect to $x$. So $w$ is $kx$ times what you wrote.  We can't find $dy/dx$ in a very simple way because the expression for $y$ involves both $x$ and $t$.

Comment: Alright this slowly making more sense now, $w$ = $k \over 2\sqrt(ln|x|)$ since the $x$ values cancel out, $\delta y \over \delta t$ = $ksin(t) \over 2\sqrt(ln|x|)$ + $cos(t)\sqrt(ln|x|)$ ? Also I just want to know why $kx$ must times $\delta \over \delta t$$\sqrt(ln|x|)$

Comment: The answer is now right. It is not that we must multiply $\frac{d}{dt}(\sqrt{\ln x})$ by $kx$. We must multiply $\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{\ln x})$ by $kx$, which is $\frac{dx}{dt}$. Chain Rule at work.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for this I really appreciate the help, it actually looks a lot simpler now that I look at it. I think what threw me off was the $f(x, t)$ but now it makes more sense.

Comment: You are welcome. It is straightforward, but one needs good control over the Chain Rule.